# Tkinter opening two windows instead of one

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a checkers game GUI, and i can't seem to figure out why it keeps opening two windows instead of the one i initialize.
Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/s7XWLdfY
And here's a screenshot:[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjjGr.png)

Any help would be really appreciated, i'm fairly new to tkinter.

```
def init():
    global root
    global extraref #creates a reference to the pieces images
                    #so they don't get garbage collected
    extraref = np.array([tk.Label() for item in range(64)]).reshape(8, 8)

def switch(board, val):
    switcher = {
        Board.E: "imgs/E.gif",
        Board.W: "imgs/W.gif",
        Board.B: "imgs/B.gif",
        Board.DW: "imgs/DW.gif",
        Board.DB: "imgs/DB.gif",
    }
    return switcher.get(val)

def refresh(board): #refreshes the board after a turn
    mat = board.getMat()
    #print(mat)
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            path = switch(board, mat[i][j])
            #path = "imgs/B.gif"
            tmp_img = Image.open(path)
            img = itk.PhotoImage(tmp_img, master=root)
            
            extraref[i][j] = tk.Label(root)
            extraref[i][j].img = img
            extraref[i][j].config(image = extraref[i][j].img)
            butts[i*8+j].config(image = extraref[i][j].img)
            extraref[i][j].pack()

init()
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=800, background="white")
frame.pack_propagate(0)
frame.pack()

lab = tk.Label(frame)
lab.pack()

butts = list()
for i in range (8):
    for j in range (8):
        lab.grid(row=i, column=j)
        butt = tk.Button(lab, bg=("black" if i%2 != j%2 else "white"))
        #butt.config(height=5, width=8)
        #butt.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
        #butt.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)
        butts.append(butt)
        butt.grid(row=i, column=j) #creating button grid

board = Board()
refresh(board) #places pieces on the grid

root.mainloop()
```

P.S: for the complete code please check pastebin, i had to cut some functions to be able to post it

Comment: `tk.Label()` inside `init()` will create the first window.  `root = tk.Tk()` will create the second window.  Maybe calling `init()` after `root = tk.Tk()`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Could you post this as an answer so i can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `tk.Label()` inside `init()` function which will create the first window.  Then `root = tk.Tk()` will create the second window.

You should call `init()` after `root = tk.Tk()`:

```
root = tk.Tk()
init()
frame = ...
```